# Default Parameters or kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, there are a few different ways to set default keyword arguments in a function. The ways I know of are:

```
def default(para_1: str = "this is", para_2: str = "an example"):
    print(para_1, para_2)
```

and:

```
def keyword(**kwargs):
    para_1 = kwargs.get("para_1", "this is")
    para_2 = kwargs.get("para_2", "an example")

    print(para_1, para_2)
```

Both of these functions can be called like so:

```
default(para_1="this is", para_2="another example")
keyword(para_1="this is", para_2="another example")
```

to achieve the same effect. The only difference I know of between the two methods are when using mutable default values, where default parameters would need to be written as:

```
def mutable_default(para_1: dict = None):
    if para_1 is None:
        para_1 = {}
```

while the kwarg method wouldn't need to be re-structured in the same way, as it is safe with mutable defaults:

```
def mutable_keyword(**kwargs):
    para_1 = kwargs.get("para_1", {})
```

Is there a preferred method between the two?

Comment: There is a big difference: it is quite obvious how to call the first function, but not at all how to call the second one. If you know which arguments it takes, specify them always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use real arguments as much as possible, because they will be shown in the function's `help()`. Seeing that a function has a signature `(**kwargs)` tells you nothing about what arguments it accepts. Seeing the signature `(search_term, whole_word=False, case_sensitive=True)` is much more valuable.

Using good names is a form of documentation and reduces the need to write other documentation (and the likelihood it will go out of date due to changes in the code).

Comment: When would be the case when it's better to use the **kwargs? Can you give an example?

Comment: When you're calling another function but don't know which function or what arguments it takes.

Comment: How could I call a function and not know what arguments it would take? Something like this? `def default(para_1= "this is", para_2= "an example", **kwargs): print(para_1,para2);func(**kwargs)` Any concrete example?

Comment: Most decorators, for example. It's common for decorators to create a wrapper function that calls the decorated function, and substitute this for the original function. You don't know what function will be decorated when you're writing the decorator. Your wrapper will therefore accept `*args` and `**kwargs` and pass these along to the decorated function.